# What are these strange POST requests trying to do?

Tags: security, nginx, web

I have a website, and I get some strange POST request every day. The request IP is different every day.

The interval between two requests is two minutes, and these last for several hours.

Here are some of the logs from Nginx today, the last item of every row is the request body.

`68.2.122.219 - - [05/Mar/2017:02:47:14 +0800]  "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2597  "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"  "F6BalN/BMT7wx1mr2qUHw6NKNerhd48AR/SfLoWpA9qneyTE4erO5DpSkeRutrJMpDjm1MRCpMinEhQ8W3kpsHJMqQ9TW+lTxAXyLslIV1N51/DVUygQRlvd3fAvREo1DalJlbEKbTItNb1EhbjLb7cYL631QfCwk9jkUUywb9oVmwuldzDrwgOycH4xzTeXnYesvLLKqQj7tioqGcPKk0q/u9otCVoQQCkNXuRd3oZvYRRwgEjvJaaTAyHeb5Zim1j2DOR1DAHi767jPLpVZV5dZC18/gB8wsztnJOB1r3U/pY1Eb8EYk6Yns/fIN3H2W2eARr4PZnCnYm4sZEKDW7vNajyyi6FRMLtBvz3kTGRiN1S5oSd1Whw"
68.2.122.219 - - [05/Mar/2017:02:49:14 +0800]  "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2597  "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"  "SqZZk4nKZxnLVbk3N638kNB7jLTgdJqowSIB3DAvf1qFEhUPI8b4BnJzP/arzARH/FG7kCqpkozJl3ma//L1lk2rIFlpFz3iIv14FNkHqCLhAOdznDTM2328MGAyFY+Y7esrYwNOur4jvt6i8IOYDg9U7p8VI2VspTkP2TpjLB+gsbjevgxrVAys02yWvmSOhzFxmDTAOCQjEQUuW859RmzpezIHIro4G32wtRXCknm42xzFX++E2ADmd+G74LV2uc6HcHqLJVJgzIh5j45C17xYt25WRNlswCbWuswTZTapd0BbwF5nEWjSg9PHz2k65MBJ6GLu+6MTlUfk1wdODVEyKnlrEyMLOeu96n+mvFglcarFAv9nITMkqxhCGHEsRXCc6nKMJ4DeiqpFYjllnLV1/0ctBLPtX+3xePEguA=="
68.2.122.219 - - [05/Mar/2017:02:51:14 +0800]  "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2597  "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"  "RqJYxt6ZZVFh811Tel5cH8ip4w+zl1fuJ0PJTM6Mdghbfh2yihGMo7H1/pKC57Yw6nRVQsphJxSYsjJDjA5xONOmTcqrAIilupI9Odqhg2rNbJ4MrgMLSnjjmUji72mT0CKav/bzubbk7ZhYor944yyji+oF8kNBIV5Ti+K/0T/Tjl1Aev0tAHH13QbFf5ARFTC19k5lojJZbFyhGXq+jRDFKLAPDulLCFYl1Zovuew7bcbAhf6CFAiFnxu/yutLNdwl2mRws5Lj7jtxA/yhkcoGTo27gXBvuRxgDN+vQ3jvUVqqbyzQh0aWyq0Du4OU3KPFN6DA76NhoD59F+NHrz3pO/3nmR5XKVE8QErsIgV4LsGgr/EiWQ=="
68.2.122.219 - - [05/Mar/2017:02:53:15 +0800]  "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2597  "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"  "E6JawtybNX9sCC6lSod2Qam8J/uZAjuSzI9YAhnDIAnhmaxqXWV1XnMz+AdzqFuRreARv1F5fTLa+J2Jmcet+SUxWTQ8WLbNUemscrO3/9kKpTw4BdPj7HD1Q/VouM8Yfh71sTNd9CBKZeF1ysqyZY9LGsE1/GzXTkv92zR7L4EeYp1qyNJs/nDAUClfI80+/uRRRKQNcWX/avwif7LYuGntqdtmnVSIepJGJgyCWIjBGAKmcgGIVz5HVN5lVcWbWRLKxAo7rTn7o1R4I2TSBLpb59o7xE4xLz4Aj4c3IQp6t6EoIuB4OmfZLB3pzR6D9imt2e7gX3LWCgYTYgKHS/G6psVRelPqq8Nl76llGb4UischUHPhMY+a7Tdnp713Qvmn3NqNOA=="
68.2.122.219 - - [05/Mar/2017:02:55:15 +0800]  "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2597  "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"  "FPMPx9/OYex0jPlrLAbHN6HpbERjBv9lTy17LvSkX1QB2VDUj5COMN4YXSdCkLz0sJCCVbaQbKGVKQd8arBE24NraKtu1HSg2WLyqJGm06I8sfUQvYLJSWMoh2H8m1TmWan3TlqU7Ay62PBIVKBiRv3wYTf/LYcGhms2mYcayjHbOn5CffTNYA+cgc6Difpcul83a33b7njHWgTK8Yi+yACHkqhSu40xVUFF0UORDR8vkUa1FUpDBC1IMjL/2ZjOO+chV2W44ZwmB9KrMZ7e9pm/ox8X6obVFdUE/slJrdFxIo+pzpT+zbEWmkfQ7TdQy7pyEaslaIhmA345kzItn/2+lgY3swMZOFc7AN0qkKFTMPOIBswOi+w="
68.2.122.219 - - [05/Mar/2017:02:57:16 +0800]  "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2597  "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"  "QaZYxYjNYaJxZAcHMtK5FpjVT7U0wMMuQVRk8lCqpq4OMSwNnhSzws3IVGQU5flmBBBowd4zS66jRuRpil3kf0IjbKk3VstjNyvlarNoh2Cy5jv1q5gefcqEnVDgbiZjkjlucorQWdNeMtovXsRU9Daau0vxA2rj2ih6O3wlskCbAwhPh3wUV7gvuKwAtKgSs+lqCHtn2+SAO+pj+Vsmt7lTmOGc067/CUdH8d1aYUPJZyWVxXKJGn2MazuWHbbv6x2k/P3QCvYJqBkvvriLUpNFwtUbLw45qc/IF5DrQCGAUsFNwyaU6wSt0o/pF/GbS2b93laNBcsyiFwb1aQc0M6xGr1TpbWSGWgr"
......
68.2.122.219 - - [05/Mar/2017:03:23:21 +0800]  "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2597  "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"  "FKZcl4ydbeNCQ+nct2+wosy3Z5BMNOVDY5OHfyJUeKN0E9Cscfo9HcxRi6OQAOWULQNK9DQOLjrJP8iA3Pk54IJcO8f9wAyubDdYX4aerbmASZ6pYyfTe8v8a9t/Al+AGVP2Nw1PcCfQVlrDEDIq7jjs3Ul3qvvfr8F8FB4kmVRwVrMEpDnRHbEUgn2WPGdmRzVXJeY3L/cOU2Ys+2bdo/dRwpU0rimpH3iXFa0lpHP29YH0jAekSXx/kjDm+d2QlfLHVQihThsXIw+tmd+CZbiQo5CdCjgW9C1JaqMXVSp9QQBkjwjBWxPs9DNQM6lLgSybZw0GnGcGxFoIhVEL1GDLj7WPsDD4g7fEa73M/mc="`

I've tried to decode the request body using base64, but I can't find out anything human-readable.

What are these requests trying to do? Are they harmful?

Comment: Something on your server accepts them and sends back a status 200.

Comment: @Henry Yes, my server returns HTML just like these are GET requests, but I still wonder what these requests want to do.

Comment: This is probably a very good question for security.stackexchange.com. It's offtopic here (it's not programming related), but it's a very good question and worth taking there.